# Multi-monitor set-up: Prevent OSX from changing main displays when switching HDMI input

Tags: macos, mac, hdmi, window

I use a multi-monitor set up with my Macbook Pro Retina (2012) where I connect one 24-inch monitor through a DVI to mini-display cable and a 32-inch monitor using an HDMI cable. The 32-inch is my main display and is connected via an unpowered HDMI switch. I also have an Xbox One connected to the HDMI switch and whenever I switch inputs to the Xbox, the Macbook thinks that I disconnected my main 32-inch display and gathers all the windows on my 24-inch display. Is there any way to prevent OSX from switching main displays? Would it help if I used a powered HDMI switch (i.e. that has its own power supply)? I just want OSX to recognize that the monitor is still connected to the laptop and prevent it from switching main displays.

Previously, I only had the 24-inch connected to my Macbook through the DVI port. The Xbox was connected directly to the display's HDMI port. Whenever I switched inputs using the monitor controls, OSX did not switch main displays.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: at a guess, you'd need something that 'fakes' the screen still being alive when you switch over, otherwise the compy's just doing its job & making sure you don't lose windows off-screen.

Comment: Do you think that a powered HDMI switch will do the trick (similarly to just connecting to the DVI port and using the monitor's own input controls)?

Comment: possibly - but I wouldn't like to guess